# keras error on predict

Tags: python, django, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, keras

I am trying to use a keras neural network to recognize canvas images of drawn digits and output the digit. I have saved the neural network and use django to run the web interface. But whenever I run it, I get an internal server error and an error on the server side code. The error says **Exception: Error when checking : expected dense_input_1 to have shape (None, 784) but got array with shape (784, 1)**. My only main view is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import re
from keras.models import model_from_json
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        vari=request.POST.get("imgBase64","")
        imgstr=re.search(r'base64,(.*)', vari).group(1)
        tempimg = StringIO.StringIO(imgstr.decode('base64'))
        im=Image.open(tempimg).convert("L")
        im.thumbnail((28,28), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        img_np= np.asarray(im)
        img_np=img_np.flatten()
        img_np.astype("float32")
        img_np=img_np/255
        json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
        # load weights into new model
        loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
        # evaluate loaded model on test data
        loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
        output=loaded_model.predict(img_np)
        score=output.tolist()
        return HttpResponse(score)
    else:
        return render(request, "digit/index.html")
```

The links I have checked out are:

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901698/error-error-when-checking-model-input-expected-dense-input-6-to-have-shape-no)
- [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3109)
- [and Here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/)

**Edit**
Complying with Rohan's suggestion, this is my stack trace

```
Internal Server Error: /home/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vivek/keras/neural/digit/views.py", line 27, in home
output=loaded_model.predict(img_np)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 671, in predict
return self.model.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1161, in predict
check_batch_dim=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in standardize_input_data
str(array.shape))
Exception: Error when checking : expected dense_input_1 to have shape (None, 784) but got array with shape (784, 1)
```

Also, I have my model that I used to train the network initially.

```
import numpy
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import np_utils
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
for item in y_train.shape:
    print item
num_pixels = X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')
# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255
print X_train.shape
# one hot encode outputs
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]
# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, init='normal', activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
# build the model
model = baseline_model()
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), nb_epoch=20, batch_size=200, verbose=1)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Baseline Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

**Edit**
I tried reshaping the img to (1,784) and it also failed, giving the same error as the title of this question

Thanks for the help, and leave comments on how I should add to the question.

Comment: Check if this works outside of django. Post full stack trace. How did you train the model?

Comment: @Rohan I added the traceback stack and the original keras file, so take I look

Comment: Have you try to do something like: "img_np.reshape((None, 784))" before  "loaded_model.predict(img_np)" ?

Comment: @Dror Hillman I have tried this, but it then give the error "Value must be an integer" and fails, so this doesn't work

Comment: I think your network needs to receive the pixels one by one, or at least you are passing the `X_train` as the training set as a dataset of shape (784,1). That is 784 samples of one pixel. But you have declared your `input_dim` as 784 and the network will have that number of neurons in the input layer. Or either you change the input_dim to 1 or make the train be an array of elements with length 784.

Comment: @marquex so your saying the shape needs to be (784, 1) instead of (1,784). My goal is to pass one sample of 784 pixels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295025/valueerror-at-image-tensor-tensoractivation-5-softmax0-shape-4-dtyp/47300005?noredirect=1#comment81555441_47300005 any suggestions

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're asking the neural network to evaluate 784 cases with one input each instead of a single case with 784 inputs. I had the same problem and I solved it having an array with a single element which is an array of the inputs. See the example below, the first one works whereas the second one gives the same error you're experiencing.

```
model.predict(np.array([[0.5, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]]))
model.predict(np.array([0.5, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]))
```

hope this solves it for you as well :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295025/valueerror-at-image-tensor-tensoractivation-5-softmax0-shape-4-dtyp/47300005?noredirect=1#comment81555441_47300005 any suggesions