# predict with Keras fails due to faulty environment setup

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, typeerror, predict

I can't get Keras to predict anything. Not even in this minimalistic model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

inDim = 3
outDim = 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=inDim, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(outDim, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

test_input = np.zeros((1,inDim))
test_output = np.zeros((1,outDim))
model.fit(test_input, test_output)
prediction = model.predict(test_input)
```

Everything goes as expected until the last line:

```
Epoch 1/1
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 448ms/step - loss: 0.2500 - acc: 1.0000
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-ee244a6c7287>", line 16, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict(test_input)

  File "E:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1172, in predict
    steps=steps)

  File "E:\Programme\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 304, in predict_loop
    outs.append(np.zeros(shape, dtype=batch_out.dtype))

TypeError: data type not understood
```

I tried over and over again with different combinations of arrays and lists, but either there is that TypeError or a ValueError, because the shape is wrong.
Several answers (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950311/keras-error-on-predict)) suggest using something like

```
model.predict(np.array([[0,0,0]]))
```

But this didn't work for me, either.
Could anyone please tell me how to do this right?

EDIT: Apparently, the code was not the problem, see below.

Comment: Please fix the title of your question with something detailed and precise, an error message doesn't help. Please provide some background. Comments about what you've tried are not very helpful with out more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out the code wasn't the problem, but there was something wrong with my software. After the following steps, the above code runs without errors or warnings:

1. uninstall anaconda
2. install anaconda
3. create new environment
4. install required packages into that environment (keras, tensorflow,
   spyder...)
5. run code in that environment

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into https://colab.research.google.com and it didn't give me an error. (python2)

I did however get a warning about int to float conversion.

I would try to specify the test_input dtype explicitly as in:

```
test_input = np.zeros((1,inDim), dtype=float)
```

Since that seems to be the error message that is being output.

Comment: The dtype argument didn't change anything. But indeed, the code works on colab with Python 3.6, which is what i have installed, too.
The warnings appear independantly of the predict call and since the fit call works just fine, I'm not sure if they are linked to my error.
So maybe my installation is just broken? I will research this and update here.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and installed the Anaconda Navigator again and it got fixed.