# Issue in predict function of the trained model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I was performing a classification problem on some set of images, where my number of classes are three. Now since I am performing CNN, so it has a convolution layer and Pooling layer and then a few dense layers; the model parameters are shown below:

```
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 100, 100), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))    
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

The model runs perfectly and shows me the accuracy and validation error, etc,. as shown below:

```
model = baseline_model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=5, batch_size=20, verbose=1)
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("CNN Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

Which gives me output:

```
Train on 514 samples, validate on 129 samples
Epoch 1/5
514/514 [==============================] - 23s 44ms/step - loss: 1.2731 - acc: 0.4202 - val_loss: 1.0349 - val_acc: 0.4419
Epoch 2/5
514/514 [==============================] - 18s 34ms/step - loss: 1.0172 - acc: 0.4416 - val_loss: 1.0292 - val_acc: 0.4884
Epoch 3/5
514/514 [==============================] - 17s 34ms/step - loss: 0.9368 - acc: 0.5817 - val_loss: 0.9915 - val_acc: 0.4806
Epoch 4/5
514/514 [==============================] - 18s 34ms/step - loss: 0.7367 - acc: 0.7101 - val_loss: 0.9973 - val_acc: 0.4961
Epoch 5/5
514/514 [==============================] - 17s 32ms/step - loss: 0.4587 - acc: 0.8521 - val_loss: 1.2328 - val_acc: 0.5039
CNN Error: 49.61%
```

The issue occurs in the prediction part. 
So for my test images, for whom I need predictions; when I run `model.predict()`, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: data type not understood
```

I can show the full error if required. 
And just to show, the shape of my training images and images I am finally using to predict on:

```
X_train.shape
(514, 1, 100, 100)

final.shape
(277, 1, 100, 100)
```

So I've no idea what this error means and what's the issue. Even the data type of my image values is same `'float32'`. So the shape is same and data type is same, then why is this issue coming?

Comment: Why are you not using `channels_last` format for image ordering.?

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to [predict with Keras fails due to faulty environment setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54903852/predict-with-keras-fails-due-to-faulty-environment-setup)
I had the same issue with anaconda and python 3.7. I resolved it when I changed to WPy-3670
with python 3.6 and everything downgraded.